# Prove that $p$ is a covering map

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let  $Y$ have the discrete topology.Show that if $p:X\times Y\to X$  is projection on the first co-ordinate ,then $p$ is a covering map.

**My try**:

$p(x,y)=x$ .For each $x\in X$ consider the neighbourhood $X$ of x such that $p^{-1}(X)=X\times Y=\cup _{y\in Y} (X\times \{y\})$ where $X\times \{x\}$ is open in $X\times Y$ as $Y$ is discrete.

Also $p|_{X\times \{y\}}:X\times \{y\}\to X$ is a homeomorphism .Hence $p$ is a covering map.

Is the proof correct ?Please suggest required edits.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: thank you very much @StefanHamcke